# Dynatrace Gradle plugin & Android Gradle plugin v7.2.x

Tags: android, gradle, gradle-plugin, dynatrace

In our Android project we just apdated the Android gradle plugin to 7.2.1
after that, we have this build issue

```
Dynatrace Gradle plugin detected a plugin that is blocking auto-instrumentation due to a bug in the Android Gradle plugin v7.2.x.
  To resolve this issue, please revert to Android Gradle plugin v7.1.3 or switch to an updated version of the Android Gradle plugin.
```

Is this a knowen issue?
This is the Dynatrace plugin version I'm using

`com.dynatrace.tools.android:gradle-plugin:8.+`

Thank you in advance

Comment: This issue Is not reproductible using the version 7/3.0-beta05 of AGP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed by using the AGP 7.3.0-beta-05